# IOS async download

Tags: ios, asynchronous

My iOS app is using asynchronous download to read data from the internet. So I have events: started, done, error.

Question is about User Experience.
When data is downloading user sees Activity Indicator and I block all UI

Question is if blocking UI is a good practice?

Comment: Depends: Could the user perform another task or make headway on their current task if they weren't blocked out? Also, consider UX if they need to cancel the current download for some reason.

Comment: Assume this is login screen. You enter password and wait for login/error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an app with a similar use case: when we connect to a given system there is an XML file describing it that we must download (which is done asynchronously). Until that XML has downloaded, there's nothing the user can do with said system, and there's nothing else for the user to do (except open another system, but that's the same issue). In that case, a blocking spinner shows up in the app.

However, there are some cases where the XML won't be updated, and we can check a timestamp for that. If we don't need to update it, we don't, and the user sees no blocking spinner.

Another app that does this is Sonos - they have a blocking spinner while searching for a wireless network (with one of their systems) because they can't do anything without that connection.

Note that in both of these examples the user can still leave the app, they just can't act *in* the app.

Basically this ends up being: don't block the user unless they can do nothing until the request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you're downloading the data asynchronously then there is very little reason to block the UI since you went through the trouble to unblock it.

If there is a particular function you HAVE to block because it needs the data go ahead. But everything else should be free and responsive as normal.

Comment: this app consumes services from a web site. So when user hit action (login, post, etc) - he has to wait for result. Blocking ui looks simple (begin/stop ignoring ui events) vs making all fields readonly and check if call is in progress

Comment: Blocking the UI will always be easier. That doesn't mean its the right thing to do. A iOS device is all touch. So if the user touches and the screen doesn't respond it feels broken or worse, frozen. I can't tell you what is best for your app. But I can tell you that blocking UI is NEVER best practice.